# How to wait for function to execute and get proper promise response?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, johnny-five

I'm creating website using Johnny-five,React and node.js to control my Arduino board but I got stuck on handling async/await function. So, user is sending chosen port (COM1) for example to server, server then creates new instance of board

```
async function checkPortConnection(port) {
    let board = new five.Board({port: port});
    let success;

    await board.on('error', () => {
        success = false;
    });

    await board.on('ready', () => {
        success = true;
    });

    return success;
}
```

I've thought that keyword await will stop function execution and wait for board response which takes about 7 seconds, but when I do this:

```
checkPortConnection(port).then((data)=>{
            console.log(data);
        });
```

I'm getting 'undefined', (because I'm getting `success` which is undefined?)
And after that server will send response if chosen port is correct or not.
But my question is, how to get proper response from `checkPortConnection()` function?

Comment: I don't know the five library you are using, but since the `on` function has a callback, it probably does not return a promise... You would need to wrap you entire return value in a promise and then `resolve` or `reject` depending on which event gets fired. Otherwise it will just register the event handler and return the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are listening for events, but this in and of itself isn't a Promise. Also, if they would be and you would use `await` you would never reach the code to register the `ready` event. The following should fix that issue:

```js
async function checkPortConnection(port) {
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
      let board = new five.Board({port: port});

      board.on('error', error => resolve( false ));
      board.on('ready', event => resolve( true ));
    
    });
    
}
```

Personally I would also do the following, as the Promise will either use `then` or `catch` later, so you might want to ignore the boolean bit altogether:

```
board.on('error', reject);
board.on('ready', resolve);
```

Comment: `reject` should only be called with an `Error`, so +1 to the second option. If you want this Promise to resolve to `true` or `false` instead, then both the `error` and `ready` handler should call `resolve` instead.

Comment: @jacob that is indeed true, good catch (edited post). I prefer the second solution as well, as any info about the event or error gets passed on nicely and can be acted upon properly. No loss of information there.